# How to sign a GET request containing a query parameter with a space

Tags: java, http, twitter, request, sign

Wanting to consume the [Twitter search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/premium-search), all my tests are OK excepted the ones which contain a space on my search query.

Ex: a search with `@RedouaneBali has:mentions` query builds the following request :

`Request{method=GET, url=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/tweets/search/30day/dev.json?fromDate=201912261403&toDate=202001251248&maxResults=100&query=%40RedouaneBali%20has%3Amentions, tags={}}`

and ends with this `{"error":{"message":"Could not authenticate you."}}`

So I concluded that the signing part was KO because of the space (without any space on my query everything is working well). I tried to remplace it by `%20` or `+` but it doesn't work neither. I'm using this [Oauth1SigningInterceptor class](https://gist.github.com/serj-lotutovici/f85518e99b23008b3180) to sign my requests.

Debugging inside, I see that my the query parameter is first transformed from `@RedouaneBali has:mentions` to `%40RedouaneBali+has%3Amentions` and then as `%2540RedouaneBali%2Bhas%253Amentions` so it may come from here but it is not so clear to me. Is it normal to have this double signature ?

Any idea about how to transform it to `%20` instead of `+` or `%2B`?

[Twitter Doc](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/oauth-1-0a/percent-encoding-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a ESCAPER problem, 
`UrlEscapers.urlPathSegmentEscaper()` transforms a space in `%20` whereas 
 `UrlEscapers.urlFormParameterEscaper()` transforms a space in `+`.
The double transformation is apparently normally based on twitter documentation.
See the fixed file [here](https://github.com/redouane59/social-media-raiser/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/socialmediaraiser/core/twitter/signature/Oauth1SigningInterceptor.java)